# Aramaic dictionary online

Tags: grammar-dikduk, language, aramaic, dictionary, lexicon

I'm looking for a good easy to use online aramaic dictionary that is free to use.

Anyone know of one?

Aside from jastrow and cal

Comment: I don't think you're going to do better than Jastrow.